# operator FIELD_NAME IS NULL is not working

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have a map of soil properties. I am trying to exclude areas that are designated for protection from a selection on this map.

I have tried to use the following query:

```
SOIL_TEXTURE = 'clay' AND SPA_NAME IS NULL but this does not work
```

Comment: you must use double quote for fields names.

Comment: I have double quoted field names but it still doesn't work

Comment: More info is needed. Can you share a screenshot of the attribute table?

Comment: So ? Has it been solved ?

Answer (score 1):

Field names need to be double-quoted in your expression. See, for example, the [QGIS documentation on expressions](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html).